# Refreshing a page without reloading it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So within a website is a div that contains another part of the website being loaded when a tab is clicked.

So let's say clicking a tab loads up a file called "hive/index.php". When someone clicks on an option in an autocomplete, I only want to reload hive/index.php and still have the rest of the page, not the entire webpage. How do I do that?

Comment: Something like [load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) or [ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: well, load just refreshes the whole page, when I still need to stay on a certain tab. All I'm aiming for is to have THAT php reloaded, and not the entire page.

Comment: No, `load()` will load data into a specified element. That element could be the container for this "certain tab" and the data could be from "THAT php".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If using jQuery,

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>   
$('#divID').load('hive/index.php'); //<- Use this on any event in which you want to refresh the content
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, and wrap that in an onClick handler for the complete solution.

Comment: Yeah, should be binding it to the div itself, I forgot. Thank you.